# Proof that Lukaszyk-Karmowski metric upper bound Wasserstein metric

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I was reading [Introduction to Uncertainty Quantification](https://books.google.com/books?id=Sik3CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=%C5%81ukaszyk%E2%80%93Karmowski+wasserstein&source=bl&ots=XbPrKM2ciU&sig=n6a6lt1rfgh3KRrQP97eTyJR6cM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu2K2LjOPXAhUX6mMKHVhDCfwQ6AEIOzAG#v=onepage&q=%C5%81ukaszyk%E2%80%93Karmowski%20wasserstein&f=false) and there was an exercise for the reader, that I haven't been able to solve (Exercise 5.11).

Given $(X,d)$ is a metric space equipped with a Borel $\sigma$-algebra. $\mu$ and $v$ are both probability measures.

Let $$d_W(\mu, v) = \inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma(\mu,v)} \int_{X\times X} d(x,x')d\gamma(x,x')$$
where "the infimum is taken over the set $\Gamma(\mu,v)$ of all measures $\gamma$ on $X \times X$ such that the push-forward of $\gamma$ onto the first copy of $X$ is $\mu$"

Also let 
$$d_{LK}(\mu,v)=\int_X \int_X d(x, x')d\mu(x)dv(x')$$

I am able to show that $d_W$ is an actual metric. But how do I show that $$d_W(\mu,v)\leq d_{LK}(\mu,v)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\mu\times\nu\in\Gamma(\mu,\nu)$$
Notice that your definition of $\Gamma(\mu,\nu)$ is not complete. In addition to what you have written, the push-forward of elements in $\Gamma(\mu,\nu)$ onto the second copy of $X$ should be $\nu$.

Moreover, your definition of $d_{LK}$ has a misprint: $\gamma\ $ should be $\nu\ $  ($\gamma\ $ has no meaning in your definition).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, could you explain a little bit more. I fixed the error in $d_{LK}$

Comment: Since $\mu\times\nu\in\Gamma(\mu,\nu)$, $d_W(\mu,\nu)$ is the infimum of a set that contains $d_{LK}$, hence cannot be greater than $d_{LK}$